# Manually set a 1D Texture in Metal

Tags: ios, swift, gpgpu, metal

I'm trying to fill a **1D texture** with values manually and pass that texture to a compute shader (these are 2 pixels that I want to set via code, they don't represent any image).

Due to the current small amount of Metal examples, all examples I could find deal with **2D textures** that load the texture by converting a loaded `UIImage` to raw bytes data, but creating a dummy `UIImage` felt like a hack for me.

This is the "naive" way I started with -

```
...
var manualTextureData: [Float] = [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                                   0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ];
let region: MTLRegion = MTLRegionMake1D(0, textureDescriptor.width);
myTexture.replaceRegion(region, mipmapLevel: 0, withBytes: &manualTextureData, bytesPerRow: 0);
```

but Metal doesn't recognize those values in the shader (it gets an empty texture, except for the first value).

I quickly realized that the Float array probably has to be converted into a bytes array (e.g `UInt8`), but couldn't find a way to convert from `[Float]` to `[UInt8]` either.

Another possible option I consider is using a `CVPixelBuffer` object, but that also felt like a workaround to the problem.

So whats the right way to tackle that?

Thanks in advance.

- Please note I'm not familiar with **Objective-C**, hence I'm not sure whether using `CVPixelBuffer` / `UIImage` is exaggerated for something which should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 2):

Please forgive the terse reply, but you may find it useful to take a look at my experiments with Swift and Metal. I've created a particle system in Swift which is passed to a Metal compute shader as a one dimensional array of Particle structs. By using posix_memalign, I'm able to eliminate the bottleneck caused by passing the array between Metal and Swift.

I've blogged extensively about this: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/Metal

I hope this helps.

Simon

Answer (score 1):

If you want a float texture bytesPerRow should be 4 for times the width, because a float has a size of 4 bytes. Metal copies the memory and dont care about the values. That is your task ;-)

Something like:

```
myTexture.replaceRegion(region, mipmapLevel: 0, withBytes: &manualTextureData, bytesPerRow: manualTextureData.count * sizeof(Float));
```

Comment: The Metal specification states that 1D Textures (only) need to set bytesPerRow to 0 :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason for you to pass data using 1D texture. Instead I would go with just passing a buffer. Like this:

```
var dataBuffer:MTLBuffer? = device.newBufferWithBytes(&manualTextureData, length: sizeOf(manualTextureData), options: MTLResourceOptions.OptionCPUCacheModeDefault)
```

Then you hook it to your `renderCommandEncoder` like this:

```
renderCommandEncoder.setFragmentBuffer(dataBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 1)//Note that if you want this buffer to be passed to you vertex shader you should use setVertexBuffer
```

Then in your shader, you should add parameter like this `const device float*  bufferPassed [[ buffer(1) ]]`

And then use it like this, inside your shader implementation:

```
float firstFloat = bufferPassed[0];
```

This will get the job done.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah - I know about the buffers and I've used them in numerous other places.
Is there any benefit for using 1D Textures over Buffers when possible?
I thought they might use the same hardware.
The 1D texture should contain a pre-calculated color palate that all my kernels need to read from as input. While Buffers could be used here, I thought that Textures would be a more optimized since only the color parameter matters..

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering your question, but you could just define an array in your metal shader instead of passing the values as a texture.

Something like:

```
constant float manualData[8] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                               0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 };

vertex float4 world_vertex(unsigned int vid[[vertex_id]], ...) {
    int manualIndex = vid % 8;
    float manualValue = manualData[manualIndex];
    // something deep and meaningful here...
    return float4(manualValue);
}
```