# iOS: How to manually set a 2D Float data to MTLTexture or MPSImage?

Tags: ios, swift, convolution, metal

I'm trying to fill `MPSImage` or 2D Metal texture with values manually and pass that to do convolutional network operation. An input for CNN (Metal Performance Shaders) is usually an image (like this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MPSCNNHelloWorld/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017482-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), that's why I could pass `UnsafePointer` of `CGContext`, but this time I'd like to use Float array as an input.

The following is what I tried. I converted an input array to `NSData`, but it didn't work.

```
var inputData = NSData(bytes: inputFloatArrayOfArray, length: inputFloatArrayOfArray.count * inputFloatArrayOfArray[0].count * MemoryLayout<Float>.size)
// The type of inputFloatArrayOfArray is [[Float]] 
network.srcImage.texture.replace(region: MTLRegion( origin: MTLOrigin(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0),
                                                    size: MTLSize(width: inputWidth, height: inputHeight, depth: 1)),
                                 mipmapLevel: 0,
                                 slice: 0,
                                 withBytes: &inputData,
                                 bytesPerRow: inputWidth * MemoryLayout<Float>.size, 
                                 bytesPerImage: 0)
```

[Manually set a 1D Texture in Metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694821/manually-set-a-1d-texture-in-metal) may relate to my question (FYI: it says "deal with 2D textures that load the texture by converting a loaded `UIImage` to raw bytes data, but creating a dummy `UIImage` felt like a hack for me." ), but it seems there is no enough answer. Now I have no ideas how to tackle this. Please let me know anything if you have any ideas.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think you're already quite close to a solution, but I don't think you need to use `NSData` as an intermediary here; that just creates an unnecessary copy. What's important is that the data in the array is laid out contiguously in the expected order. That seems to imply that you should create a single array (not an array of arrays) that contains the rows of your image data laid out "end to end", and then pass that array directly as the bytes parameter (since a Swift array can be implicitly cast to the appropriate unsafe raw pointer type).

Comment: Thank you very much. I converted Array of Arrays to Array. Are there any ways to check whether the texture could load the correct numbers or not?

Comment: You could read the bytes back programmatically and verify them, or create a render loop and do a GPU Frame Capture within Xcode to view all of the existing resources.

Answer (score 0):

If your tensor has <= 4 feature channels, then you just copy them in with feature channels 0-3 sitting where RGBA would be in the texture. If your tensor has more than that, then you use a MTLTexture2DArray instead. Additional feature channels beyond the first four go consecutively into the same coordinate in later images in the array.

```
Image[0]: // a.k.a. slice 0
  pix[0][0] = {feature channel 0, feature channel 1, feature channel 2, feature channel 3}

Image[1]:  // a.k.a. slice 1
  pix[0][0] = {feature channel 4, feature channel 5, feature channel 6, feature channel 7}

Image[2]:  // a.k.a. slice 2
  pix[0][0] = {feature channel 8, feature channel 9, feature channel 10, feature channel 11}
```